# HTML relative link links to the anchor covered by the navbar

Tags: html, css, position, navbar

When I create a relative link in HTML, `<a href="workshops.html#bot" class="btn btn-primary">Bot Workshops</a>` it links properly, but places the anchor at the top of the page, covered by a navigation bar. Is there a way to make it be lower so that the anchor is underneath the navbar?

Comment: sounds like a css issue, can you recreate the page using https://jsfiddle.net/ so we can see the issue

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE], preferably as a StackSnippet (the `<>` button in the question editor). We are guessing without a more complete example of what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, when the user clicked `<a href="workshops.html#bot" class="btn btn-primary">Bot Workshops</a>`, it should go underneath the navbar.

In your navbar, add an id. For example:

```
<div id="bot"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to change the display of the anchor link.

```
a {
    display: block;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a `padding-top` to the #bot div (approx the height of the navbar plus some space). (This is based on some assumptions below)

I think your navbar is fixed?

If that is the case, the top of the #bot anchor div will be on the top-edge of the browser viewport. But the navbar will be obfuscating some of that content underneath.

This is more of a css/styling issue.

If you do add a padding-top, you might also want to make sure that value is responsive.